# How do I fix my slideshow going over my sticky navbar?

Tags: html, css

**1)** I followed a tutorial from W3schools for a [sticky navbar header](https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_navbar_sticky.asp) and tried making a slideshow underneath it on the home page of my demo website. (For the slideshow, I also followed a [W3schools tutorial](https://w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp) for it.)

I noticed that whenever I scrolled down to view my content, the slideshow would always overlap and go on top of my sticky navbar header.

Here is a [screenshot of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sT3mR.png).

**2)** Also, how do I center the links in the sticky header? I've tried doing `left: 35%; position: relative;` to center it a bit more but it isn't fully centered. (The code is commented under `#navbar a` in the CSS section.)

Thank you for your help!

My code:

```css
/* Navbar */
.logo {
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

#navbar a {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: gold;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  float: left;
  display: block;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* left: 35%;
  position: relative; */
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Slideshow */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav>
      <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#about-us">About Us</a>
        <a href="#prices">Prices</a>
        <a href="#now-showing">Now Showing</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Slideshow -->
    <br>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/people-at-the-cinema.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">We Have Renovated!</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/playmobil-poster.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">In Cinemas August 9</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/frozen-2-poster.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">In Cinemas November 22</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

**Answer of first question** is set `z-index` to `9000` of header `nav` so that it comes above slider.

**Answer of second question** remove `float` of anchor tag ans set `inline-block` instead of `block` and on parent `text-align: center`

> Here is a snippet

```css
/* Navbar */
.logo {
  height: 10%;
  width: 15%;
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#navbar {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 9999;
}

#navbar a {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  color: gold;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2rem;
  /* left: 35%;
  position: relative; */
}

#navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Slideshow */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
}

.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-family: "League Spartan";
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.dot {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active,
.dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 0.4;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Navbar -->
    <nav>
      <div id="navbar">
        <a href="#about-us">About Us</a>
        <a href="#prices">Prices</a>
        <a href="#now-showing">Now Showing</a>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Slideshow -->
    <br>
    <div class="slideshow-container">
      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/people-at-the-cinema.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">We Have Renovated!</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/playmobil-poster.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">In Cinemas August 9</div>
      </div>

      <div class="mySlides fade">
        <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
        <img src="../../media/frozen-2-poster.jpg" style="width: 100%">
        <div class="text">In Cinemas November 22</div>
      </div>

      <!-- Next and previous buttons -->
      <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
      <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
    </div>
    <br>

    <!-- The dots/circles -->
    <div style="text-align:center">
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span>
      <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span>
    </div>
```